# UpsetR - choosing intersections to visualize

Tags: r, upsetr

I would like to use Upset plot instead of venn diagram to show overlap between specific groups (20 in total). However, one of the group (number 10) is the most important for me and I would like to present how many unique values is in that specific fraction. I would like to present ~25-30 intersections in total on the graph but uniqueness of group 10 has to be also shown.

I know existence of `sets` function but I would like to present around 25-30 intersections as mentioned and this 1 group additionally.

Any ideas ?

EDIT:
Added reproducible example:

```
dput(rep_exp)
structure(list(Gr_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                        NA, 24.4310955935393, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Gr_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, 21.8310535918369, 
                                                                  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.7254228450715, NA, 27.1619253143803, NA, 
                                                                  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 26.6027203831498, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                  NA, 30.8729830402671, NA, NA, NA), Gr_6 = c(28.8390902059829, 
                                                                                                              24.67734371881, 22.683139406727, 29.1546773298581, NA, NA, 21.9107159172821, 
                                                                                                              NA, 22.9230495998744, 26.9880437180908, NA, 32.391666051163, 
                                                                                                              NA, NA, NA, 21.6001415858001, 23.0239282537894, NA, 21.055168555216, 
                                                                                                              30.7121903523751, NA, NA, NA, NA, 22.0963548474675, NA, 32.513357598066, 
                                                                                                              NA, NA, 23.7976852708585), Gr_7 = c(21.4265985064224, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                  23.0695638371137, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.7903453146324, NA, 28.2499758022535, 
                                                                                                                                                  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 25.9613085520105, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                  NA, NA, 29.355377815192, NA, NA, 21.1302512982254), Gr_8 = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 21.8730880931062, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 22.4189005564519, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                               NA, 30.2275670312356, NA, NA, NA), Gr_9 = c(22.195894810917, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           25.9203441316619, NA, 23.5317193622031, NA, NA, NA, 20.4526193062251, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           NA, 22.357699113594, 19.9767319209274, 29.0184743803346, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           NA, NA, NA, 22.1010446624755, NA, NA, 26.3118997535445, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           NA, NA, NA, NA, 29.9658173049532, NA, NA, 22.7388204380555), 
               Gr_10 = c(24.9716280984187, 26.6702013159945, NA, 26.0197313721615, 
                         NA, NA, NA, 22.1233522815746, NA, 24.0516716332837, 22.4063679987568, 
                         30.256761573029, NA, NA, NA, NA, 26.4434318913431, NA, NA, 
                         27.9654320211905, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 29.8212398361126, 
                         NA, NA, 24.1442935303143), Gr_11 = c(22.9856008507804, 25.1691705265075, 
                                                              NA, 26.0689081411402, NA, NA, NA, 21.1400234004731, NA, 24.5711480491199, 
                                                              23.5402595534611, 29.329649538014, NA, NA, NA, NA, 28.6076666902364, 
                                                              NA, NA, 26.5597151498881, NA, NA, 25.8334491330428, NA, NA, 
                                                              NA, 29.7854239060885, NA, NA, 21.751849665826), Gr_12 = c(28.2942576160509, 
                                                                                                                        28.4109042369708, NA, 30.2938411874268, 28.1159976488766, 
                                                                                                                        26.6893919055319, NA, 20.2236435193017, NA, 31.1236147481775, 
                                                                                                                        27.1394614209655, 33.7497512742728, NA, NA, NA, 22.1620175455317, 
                                                                                                                        32.740995072413, NA, 23.2685659859292, 31.9204662366898, 
                                                                                                                        NA, NA, 30.7601811119423, NA, NA, 22.8704941623247, 31.3416488641037, 
                                                                                                                        NA, NA, 28.6773773257387), Gr_13 = c(27.9415091276483, 27.0299165363222, 
                                                                                                                                                             NA, 30.7110417097659, 28.7379570773404, 25.5882365428802, 
                                                                                                                                                             NA, NA, NA, 32.2667076588073, 27.2933369287433, 34.7079501935325, 
                                                                                                                                                             NA, 22.8206916170467, NA, NA, 32.5779472688676, NA, NA, 32.6317048040664, 
                                                                                                                                                             NA, NA, 30.1389490092958, 23.8308408919424, 23.0679896658325, 
                                                                                                                                                             26.164689687244, 30.2006952484736, NA, 24.447772868487, 29.5606883639626
                                                                                                                        ), Gr_14 = c(27.4616237005853, 26.7750499947566, NA, 30.3932526396929, 
                                                                                                                                     31.1062446290124, 27.2595253359549, NA, NA, NA, 33.6656430607522, 
                                                                                                                                     27.734214173453, 35.0800848727354, NA, NA, NA, 23.151279208873, 
                                                                                                                                     33.2366327906614, NA, NA, 33.4932145181405, 22.9608977649923, 
                                                                                                                                     NA, 31.8193222893087, 24.7850652730265, NA, 24.9920915833786, 
                                                                                                                                     29.0239557410047, 25.2744788247811, 26.6821750741598, 29.7891764054099
                                                                                                                        ), Gr_15 = c(27.2029382158867, 25.3112934881725, NA, 29.1103329989503, 
                                                                                                                                     29.514275096105, NA, NA, NA, NA, 31.6854120776358, 28.5249970429603, 
                                                                                                                                     35.9001903675862, 22.4465240056921, NA, NA, NA, 31.8450938083269, 
                                                                                                                                     25.5788830788713, NA, 34.7663358707296, 25.6549086895753, 
                                                                                                                                     26.2291635318221, 31.9466351025545, 26.715548983008, NA, 
                                                                                                                                     25.6752720211283, 28.4457302899793, 27.2647239196348, 25.0412216502086, 
                                                                                                                                     31.6489022687779), Gr_16 = c(25.1843096821522, NA, NA, 26.444459119903, 
                                                                                                                                                                  23.8302606418847, NA, NA, NA, NA, 27.987230611469, 27.8591095189136, 
                                                                                                                                                                  32.8816869988268, NA, NA, 24.8165571469754, NA, 28.7689442058935, 
                                                                                                                                                                  25.2395434664377, NA, 32.829999906694, 23.6787411063596, 
                                                                                                                                                                  NA, 27.8325560998723, 25.9582137297807, NA, NA, 25.6769403745901, 
                                                                                                                                                                  25.3048339598422, 23.7070405817542, 29.8423911570548), Gr_17 = c(23.2209751780558, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   NA, NA, 24.6434488773652, 22.5225058653221, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   27.0216809889885, 26.6607134339159, 31.099676534797, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   NA, 26.93077937966, NA, 27.8090060912948, 26.7795654758791, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   NA, 32.3731900255852, 24.9494014193233, NA, 24.5609834789349, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   26.086325932043, NA, NA, 25.5082418618407, 23.6504233402429, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   23.8014399755019, 28.7791270904749), Gr_18 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  NA, NA, NA, 26.0401348427439, NA, NA, 24.3341543275568, 24.7556235529872, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  30.4889365348298, NA, NA, 26.9888022043666, NA, 25.7387173773674, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  27.1316334308385, NA, 31.571451882524, NA, NA, NA, 25.745888266175, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  NA, NA, 23.2997781674234, NA, NA, 23.2402643606836), Gr_19 = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 24.3940790216008, NA, NA, NA, 21.4222413790374, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 25.7991932672173, NA, NA, 25.9372380266141, NA, 22.9217973627502, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 20.5334552143032, NA, 28.7776543930148, NA, NA, NA, 23.9298543509444, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 NA, NA, 24.3614522942989, NA, NA, NA), Gr_20 = c(NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 25.6961748124338, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 26.4582321196234, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Gr_21 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 22.8258042878256, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     NA, NA, 25.1317511650203, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

It is a code which has been used to generate a plot:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(rep_exp)) {  rep_exp[i, ][is.na(rep_exp[i, ]) == F] = rownames(rep_exp)[i]}

n_sizescale=nrow(rep_exp)*1.2

p1 <- {  upset(  fromList(rep_exp),
                 nsets = ncol(rep_exp),    nintersects = 35, order.by = "freq", #degree, freq   
                 empty.intersections = "on",    number.angles = 0, mb.ratio = c(0.55, 0.45),   point.size = 2.5,    line.size = 0.8,
                 text.scale = c(1.3, 1.3, 1, 1, 1, 1),  mainbar.y.label = "Number of groups", 
                 sets.x.label = "Groups",
                 show.numbers = "yes",  keep.order = TRUE,
                 set_size.show = TRUE,
                 set_size.scale_max = n_sizescale)
}
```

If I understood correctly the idea of dots below barplot they indicate how many groups can be found in specific intersections and a single dot gives a number for that specific `Gr` ? Am I right ?

How to force and algorithm to show couple of "interesting" groups as a single dot (show uniqueness of this group) and other as intersections.

Can you (@krassowski) rewrite a code for the package you mentioned ?

Comment: It looks like an open question, so maybe looking through my examples using a different library might give you some inspiration: https://krassowski.github.io/complex-upset/articles/Examples_R.html

Comment: I edited my answer and added an reproducible example. Can you assist me with that ?